# NSMutableDictionary Is Still Nil After Being Instantiated And Initialized

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Below is the method being called every time a speaker info is received.

```
- (void)handleGroupingFromReceivedSpeakerInfo:(SpeakerInfo *)speakerInfo
{
    GroupInfo *groupInfo = [_IP_GroupInfo_Map objectForKey:speakerInfo.mGroupIP];

    if(groupInfo == nil)
    {
        groupInfo = [[GroupInfo alloc] init];
        groupInfo.mIP = speakerInfo.mGroupIP;
        groupInfo.isTemp = YES;

        NSLog(@"HandleGrouping: New temp group %@", groupInfo.mIP);
    }

    if(groupInfo.isTemp)
    {
        if(![groupInfo.mSpeakerIDList containsObject:[@(speakerInfo.mID) stringValue]])
        {
            [groupInfo.mSpeakerIDList addObject:[@(speakerInfo.mID) stringValue]];

            NSLog(@"HandleGrouping: added new member with id %@ temp group with ip %@", [@(speakerInfo.mID) stringValue], groupInfo.mIP);

            [_IP_GroupInfo_Map setObject:groupInfo forKey:groupInfo.mIP];
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'll explain a bit about what the code does.

- Everytime a speaker info is received, it will get the stored `GroupInfo` obtained with the key, **speakerInfo.mGroupIP**
- If **groupInfo** is **nil** then simple instantiate a new one and then add the speaker info's ID into **groupInfo**
- If it is not then go on and add the speakerInfo into the existing `GroupInfo`

Ok, here's the problem, take a look at the Log(Please don't mind other Log messages, only the one that starts with "**HandleGrouping:** "):

```
Discovered speaker with id 6494094734139439904
2015-08-28 17:41:53.756 soulbeats[13558:3307] Added speakerID: 6494094734139439904 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 17:41:53.758 soulbeats[13558:1803] Discovered speaker with id 72243140485806144
2015-08-28 17:41:53.763 soulbeats[13558:3307] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 17:41:53.765 soulbeats[13558:1803] Added speakerID: 72243140485806144 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 17:41:53.770 soulbeats[13558:3307] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.772 soulbeats[13558:1803] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 17:41:53.777 soulbeats[13558:3307] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 6494094734139439904 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.779 soulbeats[13558:1803] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.785 soulbeats[13558:3307] Discovered speaker with id 7782687177520836128
2015-08-28 17:41:53.788 soulbeats[13558:1803] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 72243140485806144 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.794 soulbeats[13558:3307] Added speakerID: 7782687177520836128 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 17:41:53.802 soulbeats[13558:3307] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 17:41:53.807 soulbeats[13558:3307] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 7782687177520836128 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:55.711 soulbeats[13558:60b] SendBrowseCmd: browse again!!!
2015-08-28 17:41:55.719 soulbeats[13558:60b] SendBrowseCmd: refresh!!!
2015-08-28 17:41:55.721 soulbeats[13558:60b] Refresh: found one temp group with ip 239.11.11.12 with speakerIDListCount 2
```

As can be seen from above, the **groupInfo** was instantiated **TWICE**. You can see the log message "New temp group 239.11.11.12" appeared **TWICE**.

```
2015-08-28 17:41:53.770 soulbeats[13558:3307] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.772 soulbeats[13558:1803] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 17:41:53.777 soulbeats[13558:3307] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 6494094734139439904 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 17:41:53.779 soulbeats[13558:1803] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I get the groupInfo object with the same key, which is the ip of the speakerInfo received, **239.11.11.12**. So I am expecting that on the first call on this method, the groupInfo should be nil. But after that, since I already added a speakerInfo.mID in it and set it again to the **_IP_GroupInfo_Map** dictionary, groupInfo shouldn't be nil on next call of this method.

Additional information:

I declare NSMutableDictionary this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *IP_GroupInfo_Map;
```

What can I do to solve this? Please help. Many many thanks.

--------- UPDATE: Added NSLog(@"%@", self) --------------

```
2015-08-28 18:41:28.497 soulbeats[13652:5d03] Discovered speaker with id 7782687177520836128
2015-08-28 18:41:28.505 soulbeats[13652:1803] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1760ba90>
2015-08-28 18:41:28.507 soulbeats[13652:3903] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1760ba90>
2015-08-28 18:41:28.508 soulbeats[13652:5d03] Added speakerID: 7782687177520836128 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 18:41:28.516 soulbeats[13652:1803] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 18:41:28.518 soulbeats[13652:3903] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 18:41:28.519 soulbeats[13652:5d03] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 18:41:28.527 soulbeats[13652:1803] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 6494094734139439904 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 18:41:28.530 soulbeats[13652:3903] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 72243140485806144 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 18:41:28.531 soulbeats[13652:5d03] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1760ba90>
2015-08-28 18:41:28.543 soulbeats[13652:5d03] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 7782687177520836128 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
```

As can be seen, the id is exactly the **SAME**.

------- ANOTHER UPDATE: Added Code On How Class Is Initialized -------

```
+ (MultiroomPlay *)getMultiroomPlay
{
    static MultiroomPlay *sharedMultiroomPlay;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,
    ^{
        sharedMultiroomPlay = [[MultiroomPlay alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedMultiroomPlay;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self openSocket];

        _allSpeakersIDList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allPermGroupsIDList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allGroupsIPList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allUngroupedSpeakersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allUngroupedPermGroupsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allTempGroupsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _tempGroupMemberRemoveSeqList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        _ID_TCPConnection_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _ID_SpeakerInfo_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _ID_PermGroupInfo_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _IP_GroupInfo_Map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; // <--Look here
        _IP_PlayerInfo_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _IP_PlayBackTimer_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _IP_FinishSeqNum_Map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

--------- Added Log For Value Of GroupInfo ------------

```
2015-08-28 19:07:29.043 soulbeats[13709:3307] Discovered speaker with id 6494094734139439904
2015-08-28 19:07:29.046 soulbeats[13709:1803] Discovered speaker with id 72243140485806144
2015-08-28 19:07:29.050 soulbeats[13709:3307] Added speakerID: 6494094734139439904 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 19:07:29.052 soulbeats[13709:1803] Added speakerID: 72243140485806144 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 19:07:29.058 soulbeats[13709:3307] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 19:07:29.060 soulbeats[13709:1803] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 19:07:29.066 soulbeats[13709:3307] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1460e920>
2015-08-28 19:07:29.069 soulbeats[13709:1803] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1460e920>
2015-08-28 19:07:29.074 soulbeats[13709:3307] Value of Groupinfo: (null)
2015-08-28 19:07:29.076 soulbeats[13709:1803] Value of Groupinfo: (null)
2015-08-28 19:07:29.081 soulbeats[13709:3307] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 19:07:29.083 soulbeats[13709:1803] HandleGrouping: New temp group 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 19:07:29.089 soulbeats[13709:3307] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 6494094734139439904 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 19:07:29.091 soulbeats[13709:1803] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 72243140485806144 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
2015-08-28 19:07:29.098 soulbeats[13709:3307] Discovered speaker with id 7782687177520836128
2015-08-28 19:07:29.250 soulbeats[13709:3307] Added speakerID: 7782687177520836128 to AllSpeakersIDList
2015-08-28 19:07:29.332 soulbeats[13709:3307] Old speaker info is null
2015-08-28 19:07:29.380 soulbeats[13709:3307] <MultiroomPlay: 0x1460e920>
2015-08-28 19:07:29.394 soulbeats[13709:3307] Value of Groupinfo: <GroupInfo: 0x1589aad0>
2015-08-28 19:07:29.400 soulbeats[13709:3307] HandleGrouping: added new member with id 7782687177520836128 temp group with ip 239.11.11.12
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code, which leads me to believe that you have two *instances* of the class that implements `handleGroupingFromReceivedSpeakerInfo`.

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%@", self);` to that method to check?

Comment: Did you create an instance and set it to `_IP_GroupInfo_Map` ?

Comment: Other possibility is that you are running your code in a multi thread environment. If yes there there is serious issue with your code.

Comment: I think you have missed _IP_GroupInfo_Map = [NSMutableDictionary Dictionary];

Comment: Where do you alloc and initiate the dictionary?

Comment: @JamesWebster there is only one instance of the class, and all my view controllers use shares that instance of class.

Comment: @iPhone I instantiated it upon init of the class

Comment: @michaelrccurtis upon init method of the class

Comment: @JamesWebster I 'll try your suggestion by adding NSLog(@"%@", self)

Comment: @JamesWebster I updated my question.

Comment: What type of object is `mGroupIP` and `mIP`? i.e the keys you are using for the dictionary. Are they strings? custom classes?

Comment: @JamesWebster they are NSString

Comment: Hmm. I thought that `isEqual:` vs `==` could have been causing some problems, but it's not that

Comment: You're certain the method where you init the dictionary isn't being called more than once?

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes, I will post the code where I init the class, "MultiroomPlay"

Comment: @JamesWebster I added the code on how I instantiate the class

Comment: Does your code use ARC or manual reference counting?

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes, I use ARC

Comment: Why did you use `[ ... dictionary]` instead of `[[... alloc] init]` in that one case?

Comment: @JamesWebster Oh, I tried the suggestion provided by iPhone in the answer. It was alloc init before that.

Comment: Could you print out the value of the dictionary at the top of that method too please?

Comment: @JamesWebster Done. It worked properly one time. But most of the time before it doesn't. Really strange. :(

Comment: I'm not sure you've logged the right thing. I intended: `NSLog(@"%@", _IP_GroupInfo_Map);`

Comment: Oh.. do you have a custom getter for IP_GroupInfo_Map??

Comment: @JamesWebster I am thinking that, could it be that sometimes the speed of calling the method went to fast, and then before storing the groupInfo with content, another groupInfo was already instantiated and then overrided the previous one? But the problem is, I am not calling this in a multithreaded environment. There is only one instance of this class. :(

Comment: @JamesWebster I don't have custom getter and setters. I logged NSLog(@"%@", _IP_GroupInfo_Map.description);

Comment: (Just a small note, not related to this problem, you don't have to call `description`, it's called implicitly for NSLog)

Comment: You can check if you have a threading problem.. wrap the entire method in `@synchronized(self) { ... }`

Comment: @JamesWebster ok thanks. I ll try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88185/discussion-between-james-webster-and-epicninja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out your program *is* multithreaded. Surrounding your code with `@synchronized` and getting the expected output showed this.

The `@synchronized` causes the block to be executed atomically. Whereas before two threads could enter your code, both find that your dictionary was nil and both instantiate it, now the two (or more) threads each wait at the top of the synchronised block until the other(s) exit.

However, instead of just accepting "it works now", you should try and find out why is multithreaded when you didn't think it was!

---

<sub>(Parts of this issue were discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88185/discussion-between-james-webster-and-epicninja)).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in an appropriate initialisation method

```
_IP_GroupInfo_Map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the class extends NSObject